# Using MobileFirst to authenticate users with LDAP server in mobile app

Tags: ldap, ibm-mobilefirst

I followed and used this tutorial:
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/authentication-security/using-ldap-login-module-to-authenticate-users-with-ldap-server-in-hybrid-applications/

I only edit the authenticationConfig.xml and run the application

```
    <loginModule expirationInSeconds="-1" name="LDAPLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.LdapLoginModule</className>
        <parameter name="ldapProviderUrl" value="**************"/>
        <parameter name="ldapTimeoutMs" value="2000"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSecurityAuthentication" value="simple"/>
        <parameter name="validationType" value="searchPattern"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern" value="{username}"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSearchFilterPattern" value="(&amp;(objectClass=user)(cn={username})(memberof=CN=******,OU=Clients,O=******))"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSearchBase" value="OU=Clients,O=******"/>
    </loginModule>
```

When I press the "Call protected adapter" it goes to LDAP Login Module, and when I entered the user credentials, nothing happens, the password just disappears.

Here's the log:

[WARNING ] FWLSE4014W: LdapLoginModule authentication failed. Reason 'javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 2030, v1db1 
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.ContextHelper.getInitialContextUsingBuilder(ContextHelper.java:244)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.ContextHelper.getContextProvider(ContextHelper.java:208)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.ContextHelper.getInitialContext(ContextHelper.java:141)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.OSGiInitialContextFactoryBuilder.getInitialContext(OSGiInitialContextFactoryBuilder.java:51)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.LdapLoginModule.login(LdapLoginModule.java:158)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext.invokeLoginModule(LoginContext.java:252)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext.processRequest(LoginContext.java:217)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRequest(AuthenticationContext.java:510)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:182)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4730)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
' [project LDAPLoginModule]
[LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 2030, v1db1

Any idea what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried googling the exception in the error log? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c98f3569-072a-4677-9b89-635ed2b8dffc/ldap-error-code-49-8009030c-ldaperr-dsid0c0903a9-comment-acceptsecuritycontext-error-data?forum=winserverDS

Comment: Yes I've tried googling.. I'm sorry I didn't found this url.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the exception provided in the error log: `LdapLoginModule authentication failed. Reason 'javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9`

This may be related to the following: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c98f3569-072a-4677-9b89-635ed2b8dffc/ldap-error-code-49-8009030c-ldaperr-dsid0c0903a9-comment-acceptsecuritycontext-error-data?forum=winserverDS

> The error code 49 related to LDAP is caused by the invalid credentials. Please refer to the following most possible causes.
>   1. The DN path or password which you have specified for the administrator is invalid. Any of the below will result in this error:
>    1). Pointed to non-user DN
>    2). Pointed to a non-existent user, but in existing DN
>    3). Pointed to non existent DN
>    4). Pointed to an existing user, but non existing DN
>    5). Pointed to an incorrect admin DN, uid instead of cn
>    6). Pointed to a non administrator user
>    7). Pointed to a valid admin but password is incorrect
>   2. Could not authenticate the user trying to login. This can be the result of an incorrect username or password, or an incorrect prefix and/or suffix specified in the Settings tab, depending on the type of LDAP/AD system.   Could also mean the authentication type is incorrect.